# Finding the Percentage of Heights

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Recently I was working on a problem using the chart shown below. I was supposed to find the percent of numbers below 74 exclusive and the percent above 83 exclusive. For both answers I got 9.09% but that is evidently incorrect. Is there something wrong with my answer?[image]

Comment: No chart is shown

Comment: no. it's seems ok. i suppose "below/above $x$ exclusive" means strictly lower/higher, right?

Comment: Was the question phrased in terms of "number of measurements" or "distinct heights"? There is only one distinct height above 83, yet 2 measurements.

Comment: The question was only phased as asking for the percentage of people with heights above 83.